# Ubuntu command 'adduser' is not creating directory 'usertes' in '/home'

Tags: useradd

I have been creating a user with command [adduser](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser), but it did not create directory `/home/usertes`,

```
# adduser usertes
```

And this happens if I delete the user with command [userdel](http://linux.die.net/man/8/userdel):

```
# userdel usertes
userdel: user usertes is currently logged in
```

Not logging on to the server, I login with *root*.

How do I create the directory in `/home` and, if logging in as usertes, the current directory will be `/home/usertes`?

As it is now, if I login, I go to directory `/`.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How do you login to root?

Comment: login with root via ssh.
$ ssh root@server-location

Comment: 'usertes' is listed as logged in, is someone connected on that username?

Answer (score 3):

I've never used `adduser` because it's never worked the way I needed it to when I create a user.  However, `useradd` does work for my needs, but by default won't create the user directory, and isn't *as* friendly to use.

`useradd --create-home USERNAME` will create the home directory using default specifications for areas, namely `/home/USERNAME`

If you want a slightly more verbose version of user-add which I find to be most useful: `useradd --create-home --user-group --shell /bin/bash USERNAME` will create the home directory, also create a group that matches the user's name (it's how `USER:USER` can be seen in home directory ownership on new installs where `USER` is the username).

After you do either of those steps, you'll need to set a password: `passwd USERNAME` (as superuser or root, to set a password, even if its temporary)